# Solving For Given Variable - How to Solve

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

So the question states: 'To convert degrees Celsius to Kelvin, the formula $K = C + 273.15$ is used. Solve this formula for $C$.'

The answer I came up with was: $K - 273.15 = C$. So is this correct? If so why not and how do I solve it?

Question #2: 'The formula $C = 2\pi r$ is used to calculate the circumference of a circle. Solve this formula for $r$.'

Answer for #2: I am completely confused what I'm supposed to do. If you guys could explain this one to me that'd be great! Else I'll just ask my teacher tomorrow.

Comment: 1. This is correct.

Comment: For 2. remember that $xy = zw$ can be written as $\frac{xy}{z} = w$ whenever $z \neq 0$.

Comment: @LorenoHeer Thank you very much for your time. I'll keep those things in mind whenever I try these problems again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving for a variable means finding a value for that variable which satisfies the given equation. In your case, you have to find a number $r$ such that $C = 2\pi r$. Now if you multiply both sides of the equation by $\frac {1}{2\pi}$ you get $\frac {C}{2\pi}=\frac{2\pi r}{2\pi}= r$, so we can see that the equation uniquely determines the value of $r$. In general when you want to solve for a variable that is multiplying some non zero constant, you multiply both sides of the equality by the inverse of the constant.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks I'll be sure to keep that in mind next time. :)

Comment: You're welcome!